# Computer Vision: Improving Region of Interests segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm running a unet model on x-ray for lung region segmentation, the model seems to work well, but my dataset is not that good looking, I'm obtaining results with some missing parts as in here:

[image]

My question is: is there any cv operator I can preform to smoothen it a little more to obtain something like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You mean a [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)?

Comment: Thanks, just checked it, after applying some erosion followed by dilation, I'm getting a result close to desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe can be implemented via `morphology`. Morphological operations are a set of (logical) operations that affect the overall shape of the image. It can "expand" or "reduce" shape regions, among many other [cool operations](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).

Let's use a dilation to expand your image's shape:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//"
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath+"lungs.png")

# Convert BGR back to grayscale:
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu + bias adjustment:
threshValue, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayInput, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This first bit converts the image that you posted into a binary image, as morphological operations can be only be performed on 1-channel images (also grayscale), but since we will apply a basic dilation, a binary image will suffice. this is the result of the above snippet:

[image]

Let's apply the `dilation`. The operation can be applied successively, so you can specify a number of `iterations`. Since you want a somewhat strong effect, let's try `10 iterations`. The operation needs a second operand named "*Structuring Element*" (`SE`), which selects the pixels in a defined sub-region of the shape. There are different kinds of `SE`s. One of the most common is a `3 x 3` `rectangular SE`:

```
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 10
# Set Structuring Element size:
structuringElementSize = (3, 3)
# Set Structuring element shape:
structuringElementShape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
# Get the Structuring Element:
structuringElement = cv2.getStructuringElement(structuringElementShape, structuringElementSize)

# Perform Dilate:
dilateImg = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, structuringElement, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Show the image:
cv2.imshow("dilateImg", dilateImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]